# How to put y axis title in top left corner of graph using grid's functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I want to write the y-axis title horizontally on top of the y-axis line **while keeping settings defined for the y-axis in the `theme()` function**. The objective is to avoid wasting space while keeping a nice looking design (*e.g*. with the title left-aligned with y-axis-ticks-labels).

I know it is possible to use other "hacks" (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512115/put-y-axis-title-in-top-left-corner-of-graph) using subtitle), but here I look for a solution using the grid approach. I am also aware that it is possible to move around the title by setting `margins` but it requires to uptade it all the time and I was not able to get a satisfying result with it.

Then, using `grid` functions as demonstrated [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54362043/10264278) seems the way to go.

Here is what I would like to get:

[image: expected output]

It is possible to start with `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1))` but the y-axis title is not on top of the line.

[image: what I have so far]

This code removes the y-axis title while keeping the `theme()` parameters defined for the grob:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 1),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
# convert from ggplot to grob object
gp <- ggplotGrob(p)
# locate the grob that corresponds to y-axis title and save its parameters
y.label.grob <- gp$grobs[[which(gp$layout$name == "ylab-l")]]$children
# remove y-axis labels from the plot, & shrink the space occupied by them
gp$grobs[[which(gp$layout$name == "ylab-l")]] <- zeroGrob()
gp$widths[gp$layout$l[which(gp$layout$name == "ylab-l")]] <- unit(0, "cm")
```

But now I am stuck as I do not know how to use functions from the `grid` package to move the title where I would like to (*i.e.* on the top left corner).

Answer (score 2):

You can exceed `vjust` beyond 1 and adapt the margins a bit. It's hard to get the alignment perfectly though.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 30),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      angle = 0, vjust = 1.1, 
      margin = margin(r = -50, t = 5.5, b = 5.5, l = 5.5)),
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

If you know the title in advance you can use it's string width.

```r
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 30),
    axis.title.y = element_text(
      angle = 0, vjust = 1.07,
      margin = unit.c(
        unit(c(2.75), "pt"),
        unit(-1, "strwidth", data = "Petal.Length"),
        unit(c(2.75, 2.75), "pt")
      )
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it is very usefull to see this "trick" to set the width just right with the lenght of the title. However I was wondering if it was possible to get something maybe more scalable than having to manually set margins (usefull when making many plots that are of different size).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cowplot` as another approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
title <- ggdraw() + 
  draw_label(
    "Petal.Length",
    #fontface = 'bold',
    x = 0,
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  theme(
    # add margin on the left of the drawing canvas,
    # so title is aligned with left edge of first plot
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 7)
  )

p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  labs(y = "")
plot_row <- plot_grid(p)
plot_grid(
  title, plot_row,
  ncol = 1,
  rel_heights = c(0.1, 1)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This technique works but it does not take into account the parameters defined in the `theme()` function for the y-axis title, which is crucial here (like fonts, size, **etc.**).

Comment: you could pass them into `draw_label` i think, but thats probably not what you want!

Comment: yes and maybe it will end up beeing more readible and feasible than trying to change grobs :/